# Comment draft discarded when Back button tapped

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, draft

There is a "down" arrow on the left side of the comment text box, the purpose of which is to discard the comment draft. When tapped on it, a confirmation message appears.

But if the user taps on the hardware/on-screen *Back* button and the app traverses to the previous screen, a drafted comment is discarded without showing any confirmation message.

I'm using version **1.0.43**.

**PS:** I'm experiencing a lot of force closes lately.

Comment: *Separated from [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234604) as suggested by ShadowWizard.*

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Hope this notifies you :)